# Why do I get coordinates of drawing feature always different?

Tags: openlayers

I subscribe on feature changes inside draw object:

```
draw.on("drawstart", (e) => {
  listener = e.feature.getGeometry().on("change", (evt) => {
    const geom = evt.target;
    if (geom instanceof Polygon) {
      var coordinates = geom.getCoordinates()[0];

      var poins = new MultiPoint(coordinates);
      console.log(poins.getPoints().length);
    }
  });
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-features-forked-poxwxy?file=/main.js

When I draw the first point the `console.log(poins.getPoints().length);` returns 3 length. Why?

Comment: Three points is a closed two sided polygon - starting at the point clicked, going to the current pointer position, then closing at the starting point.

Comment: How to check it correctly, when polygon has at less 3 points and can be closed?